# Parsing output containing non standard characters

Tags: powershell, character-encoding

I need to parse the output of the the following, as part of a pester assertion.

I want to know if the file contains a value, which happens to be a URL.

```
(Get-Content "pathTo_ANSI_file" | Where-Object { $_.Contains($someurl) }) | should be $someurl
```

The problem is the result coming back, if it does not contain $someurl, is full of characters that cause a problem when parsed and given to pester.

What is the best way to parse the output in this case, leaving only standard characters to parse?

clarification: when running a function (eg, check content of file for value), I get a result back containing non standard characters, eg:
[image: output]

I then have problems taking that output and utilizing it by something else.

I need some solution, like filtering out nonstandard characters from that output.

Comment: This is all a bit vague to me.. Can you give examples?

Comment: added illustration for additional clarification

Comment: It is still vague, `Get-Content "pathTo_ANSI_file" | Where-Object { $_.Contains($someurl) }` should not return anything if it doesn't include `$someurl`. Meaning that you can just do: `... | Should -not -BeNullOrEmpty`

Answer (score 0):

@iRon answered the question:

... | Should -not -BeNullOrEmpty

has provided a workaround to the problem.